# How to properly add marginal density plot to a ggplot object?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a marginal density plot for a `ggplot` object, denoted by `g` in the next script:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggExtra)

theme_set(theme_bw())  # pre-set the bw theme.


g <- ggplot(tidyr::spread(df, variable, value), 
            aes(`Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)`, 
                `Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)`)) +
    geom_count()+
    geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F)+
    facet_wrap_paginate(~decil, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, scales = "free") +
    geom_text(aes(label= lubridate::year(año)), hjust = 0.5,  vjust = -1)

g
```

Which returns the next plot:
[image: ggplot object]

Then, in order to get the margin density plots, the next line is run: `ggMarginal(g, type = "density", fill="transparent")` from `library(ggExtra)`,
And the next error arises:

> Error in gtable::gtable_add_grob(x = gt, grobs = topMargG, t = 1, b = 1,  :
> Not all inputs have either length 1 or same length same as 'grobs'

Expected output should have two density plots added at the margin of each axis.

What am I missing? How could I adjust this script?

### data

```
df <- structure(list(decil = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("Decil 1", "Decil 2", 
"Decil 3", "Decil 4", "Decil 5", "Decil 6", "Decil 7", "Decil 8", 
"Decil 9", "Decil 10"), class = "factor"), año = structure(c(8035, 
9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 
15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 
12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 
8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 
14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 
11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 
17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 
13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 
10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 
16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 
13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 
10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 
16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 
12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 
9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 
15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 
12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 
8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 
14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 
11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 
17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 
13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 
10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 
16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 
13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 
10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 
16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 
12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 
9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 
15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 
12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532
), class = "Date"), variable = c("Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)"), value = c(0.308138265449932, 
-2.73923609850588, -0.116791699821611, 1.276823919767, -0.591033604229833, 
2.217410209762, -1.22771361710334, 2.91323734975109, 1.9403678544531, 
-1.710307316049, 0.114882675671299, 1.31658931355581, 1.46477971543751, 
0.271712366085317, 0.274660079065288, -1.20391288467938, 0.221116802499613, 
1.68878772891571, -0.0553564396020631, 2.47304289689454, -1.49473828679342, 
2.06995781551323, 0.995111688295987, -1.23590101185821, -0.0513493069577327, 
1.57518955283768, 1.49952051319558, 0.569875774759632, 0.0595105282871455, 
-1.98229069194358, 0.692781223252039, 1.45357299983422, 0.274519154273341, 
2.50570229399105, -1.58798738651613, 1.8318771262172, 0.541185894582713, 
-1.09932567808292, 0.159443784781767, 1.38386952581564, 1.42469406477504, 
0.410413545862179, -0.144568025477976, -1.88765679042184, 1.01321912136977, 
1.16094403156238, 0.427582908849506, 2.59548917592467, -1.91921130444488, 
1.86512952445194, 0.0990294699338842, -0.837785709745078, 0.543096597486442, 
0.741481129770513, 1.29946597715581, 0.622336720429403, 0.139031953354982, 
-1.90241726271236, 0.690016525955506, 1.54716844723562, 0.256469067826587, 
2.46741215896569, -1.52082399890795, 1.46298279854535, -0.178133254716425, 
-0.570996073876508, 0.530083911456838, 0.771074074546392, 1.22148158785322, 
0.480369193797477, -0.0401792821387455, -2.1998371424533, 1.06632797701267, 
0.742663665613463, 0.534777779842798, 2.24439518748242, -1.19081274931006, 
1.26230193789639, -0.256049568632538, -0.54511282604089, 0.828289107854747, 
0.198585514462626, 1.12490515302622, 0.454776270025511, 0.308138951062849, 
-1.68702475271693, 0.963026950989102, 0.924694309980609, 0.0909783913993086, 
2.19423265975474, -1.04193226868249, 1.26951414528773, -0.599866837527287, 
-0.504144411887512, 1.2633719573124, -0.208565860801489, 1.28053568465138, 
0.223463615789722, 0.0762802869455859, -2.21763771759914, 1.08353667375486, 
1.27220562258605, -0.0199740141807546, 2.34686607111593, -1.01924956162359, 
0.996632035015618, -0.943588762041933, -0.311576607205403, 1.18147547163377, 
-0.283811580551448, 1.1151512141408, 0.256848322836834, -0.0557319323771243, 
-2.56639439214237, 1.09841238497413, 0.970528742740132, -0.041290083196072, 
2.89203820342315, -1.13995943017165, 1.0666144712339, -1.48427029516519, 
-0.237956102817481, 1.18845793975459, -0.0723117556104279, 0.578897782929168, 
0.310574312466805, 0.0420320020065887, -2.65571871864779, 1.08040626539541, 
0.501353172078248, 0.264579769939744, 3.45907008361297, -1.47337410644853, 
0.753187592344928, -1.67914957857585, -0.386430954714176, 1.18684061581655, 
-0.0837921856848724, 0.271367995890336, -0.244522199262534, 0.285801450939386, 
-0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 
0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, 
-0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 
0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, -0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 
0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 
0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, -0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 
0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, 
-0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 
0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, 
-0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 
0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, -0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 
0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 
0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, -0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 
0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, 
-0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 
0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, 
-0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 
0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, -0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 
0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 
0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, -0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 
0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, 
-0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 
0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, 
-0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 
0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, -0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 
0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 
0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, -0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 
0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, 
-0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 
0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, 
-0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 
0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, -0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 
0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 
0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, -0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 
0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 0.149656209777629)), row.names = c(NA, 
-280L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: As far as I get it the issue arises because ggMarginal doesn't work with facetting. There is an old and still open github issue on this. See https://github.com/daattali/ggExtra/issues/28.

Comment: @stefan, do you know what could be an alternative of  `facet_wrap_paginate()`,  `facet_wrap()` or `facet_grid()` for this context?

Comment: Hi Alvaro. Instead of using `facet_wrap` or ... you could make separate plots add marginal distributions and finally glue them together uisng e.g. `patchwork`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @stefan, currently I ain't trying to make a dashboard, I am trying to make a `for-loop` for a `ggplot` object, where iterative index `i` would represent a column group plot, that's the reason why `facet_wrap_paginate()` it's important as it handles the argument `page=i` ; would appreciate any ideas on how to properly ask a question about this issue.

Comment: Hi Alvaro. Don't know the details of your code. facet_wrap_paginate may be convenient to get your desired result but I'm quite sure that you don't need it to get a list of single plots to put on a dashboard. Best would be to make a simple example dashboard (flexdashboard?) to show what your are trying to achieve. And btw make your example data more minimal. (;